# fastest way to search in 3D array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

there is an array like:

```
array([
   [[X1, Y1, 80, 13, 14],
    [17, 54, 47, 67, 45],
    [11, 21, 67, 45, 11],
    [15, 75, 17, 69, 12]],

   [[X2, Y2, 94, 51, 10],
    [64, 81, 90, 80, 67],
    [78, 73, 19,  6, 57],
    [46, 18, 83, 26, 56]],

    ...

   [[Xn, Yn, 32,  3, 82],
    [47, 69, 63, 20, 10],
    [16, 48,  7, 96, 11],
    [95, 30, 45, 65, 42]] ])
```

the goal is to group by every X's and Y's then check a condition in every group.
to do this I write code:

```
x=npy.random.randint(100,size=(5,4,5))
array([[[36, 47, 80, 13, 14],
        [17, 54, 47, 67, 45],
        [11, 21, 67, 45, 11],
        [15, 75, 17, 69, 12]],

       [[50, 17, 94, 51, 10],
        [64, 81, 90, 80, 67],
        [78, 73, 19,  6, 57],
        [46, 18, 83, 26, 56]],

       [[37, 98, 32,  3, 82],
        [47, 69, 63, 20, 10],
        [16, 48,  7, 96, 11],
        [95, 30, 45, 65, 42]],

       [[59, 36, 38, 95,  3],
        [67, 62, 61, 64, 15],
        [49, 45, 24, 85, 24],
        [23, 89, 23, 63, 14]],

       [[49, 26, 70, 83, 99],
        [16, 94, 78, 43, 33],
        [95,  4, 39, 91, 56],
        [94, 26, 71, 32, 55]]])

for i in range(x.shape[1]):
  for j in range(x.shape[2]):
    npy.any(x[0:3,i,j]>80)

False
True
True
False
True
False
True
True
False
False
False
False
False
True
False
True
False
True
False
False
```

but because the array that I work with, is very big this way is not efficient to me.
is there any better way to write? is it possible to remove for loops? what is the fastest way to this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC you could simply slice the first three elements along first axis, compare against the threshold and then look for `ANY` match along the first axis -

```
(x[0:3] > 80).any(axis=0)
```

Comment: @pdshah Performs the reduction of looking for ANY match along that axis. More info - [`ufuncs docs`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be doing a lot of groups (i.e. `n` is large compared to the size of the groups) you can even use `logical_or.reduceat` to do it all at once:

```
def groupSearch(x, groupSize, c = lambda y: y > 80, axis = 0):
    slices =  np.arange(0 , x.shape[axis] , groupSize)
    return np.logical_or.reduceat(c(x), slices, axis)
```